# Windows 11 update 22H2 added 'Search' label to taskbar search button - how to remove?

Tags: taskbar, windows-11-v22h2

Just installed the latest update for Windows 11 version 22H2 for x64 (KB5020622), and after restarting the Search button on my taskbar now has been given a label 'Search' which is unnecessary and annoying. No other taskbar button has been given a label. Any ideas on how to remove the 'Search' label?

[image]

Comment: @harrymc No, I want the Search button on the taskbar - I use it quite a bit - I just don't want it to have a label. Its the only one with a label now, it doesn't need one, and it looks weird.

Comment: Right click it > Search > Show search icon, is that what you want?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen That's for Win 10 - I'm on Win11. Regardless, I have the Search button displaying, but I only want the icon visible, not the icon and the label as is shown in the screenshot since the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point in time (22H2 is still quite new and I am running it on two production machines) the label "Search" cannot natively be removed.

Nothing useful found in reasonably extensive research. What I know from following the Windows 11 Taskbar issues is that Right Click has been removed (up to this point) and the Taskbar is not changeable except what Microsoft has provided in Taskbar settings.

This may change as a result of feedback, but right now what you see is all you can do.

Windows Insider (newer version of Windows 22H2) is different again.

Also I suggest using and adapting to the way Microsoft has set this up because it may change with future releases that break any 3rd party or non-standard way of trying to change it.

**Update:  3/1/2023.** The very newest Windows 11 Update (last week of February 2023) allows Icon only, Icon with Label, Wide Search bar. So Windows 11 has changed.

Comment: you're probably right about adapting - thanks - I think I'll remove it altogether and just use Win and Win+S to Search

Answer (score 5):

You can *hide the whole search button*. You might prefer this solution, since the search button is redundant anyway -- in order to search, it is enough to open the Start menu and start typing the query, which will seamlessly switch to the search view.

To do this, navigate to **Settings > Personalization > Taskbar**, and disable the "Search" taskbar item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see how to fix the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MNOIKqefcm0
I have had the same issue and have tried. It works!

And link to Vivetool:
https://github.com/thebookisclosed/ViVe/releases/download/v0.3.2/ViVeTool-v0.3.2.zip

Comment: I see where others are suggesting this too now - might be best to come with a warning that the tool may have unexpected consequences, but thanks for the heads up anyway

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.